# Open Facebook app with predefined text to share

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

Please take a look at this piece of code:

```
 NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                       [@"Hello world!" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@", text];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:post];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

By means of this code I would like to open Facebook app installed on the device and open it on a share dialog with the `text` string used as a predefined text to share. But unfortunately what it does is just open my timeline. What am I doing wrong? Or is it even possible? I can't find any documentation or tutorial on how to do that properly. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the FacbookSDK and send the message from inside your now app.

Comment: Because the customer wants to perform sharing through the Facebook app

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill ? You can't pre-fill now.

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message of a share, it has to be a 100% typed in be the user. You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control), and also specifically check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: ok, thanks, but can I at least open Facebook app on share dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simple way using FacebookSDK's framework. This takes only 2 minutes to go.

```
FBSDKCoreKit.framework
FBSDKShareKit.framework
```

If in your device facebook app is not installed then this will open default web browser.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

// in viewdidload or somewhere else

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentTitle = @"Scare Prank";
content.contentDescription = @"Someone just got Scare Pranked with ♫";   
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundUrl];         
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@“some icon url”];

FBSDKShareButton *button = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 43)];
button.center = self.center;
button.shareContent = content;
[self addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but as I understand this demands my app to be registered at developers.facebook.com, right?